# Access Ubuntu Server VM on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I've setup an Ubuntu Server on Azure. On this server, an application is running on port 3000. I want to access this application external. Azure tells me my server has public ip 40.68.XXX.XXX.

When I ping this IP, there is no response, despite ssh works when connecting to this IP-address.

I want to access 40.68.XXX.XXX:3000 external, does somebody know how to get this work?

Comment: As stated in several places (including [here](http://serverfault.com/a/749429/99269)), ICMP isn't allowed from external sources, so `ping` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to open up a port on the Network Security Group (NSG) and open up the port on your firewall (on the VM itself).

Easiest way to open the port is using the portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: Thanks for this working solution! My next problem is how to connect a domainname to 40.68.XXX.XXX:3000? In that way I don't have to use the port number. I know I can change A records of domainname to 40.68.XXX.XXX, but how can I show port 3000 without typing it in url?

Comment: you are better off creating a new question, but you can just create a iptables rule to forward port 80 to port 3000